# Python Requests.get() doesn't work with new isp

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests.get() in Python and it was working with my previous ISP.

I moved and changed ISP for starlink and now, requests.get() doesn't return answer or only at the end of the timeout if I set a timeout.

The request is working well on my browser and I get the answer instantly.

Is there any parameter to add to the request or maybe in my isp settings to fix that ?

```py
import requests
import json

main_url = "https://api.frankfurter.app/2023-10-22?from=EUR&to=USD"

req_ob = requests.get(main_url) 
    
resultat = req_ob.json()

print(resultat)
```

I tried to add a timeout to the request parameter and the answer is coming only at the end of the timeout. I was expecting it to arrive instantly, as with my previous ISP.

I also tried with headers in parameters but same problem.

I added a proxy to the request and it worked but is there a way to avoid using proxies ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do other URLs work? Was your IP address included on an allow list for that api?

Comment: Hi, same problems for other URLs. My IP address was not on an allow list. I tried with other apis and same problem.

Comment: For urls like www.google.com i got an answer but for apis, its always the same problem. I tried api.currencyapi.com, api.exchangerate.host but no answer

Comment: This really isn't a question about writing code -- the problem and its solutions are more about network engineering / configuration / &c, and moreover, the moving parts are on the server side, outside the visibility or control of anyone here.